# Wait until sequential promise is resolved before continuing in Node

Tags: node.js

I am tryinig to setup a sequential resolve using "reduce", and then continueing on to do some other work, however it doesn't seem to be waiting, it just continues on.  How do I wait for every promise in the array to finish?

```
function Work(data){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{resolve()});
}
function DoWork(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            Work(data)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Doing work on '"+data+"'");
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("Failed to do work on '"+data+"'");
                    reject(err);
                });
        }, 1000);
    });
}
var AllMyWork= ["a","b","c"];
AllMyWork.reduce((p, data) => p.then(DoWork(data)), Promise.resolve())
.then(result => {
    console.log("All work is finished");
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("MyArray reduce has failed");
});
```

Here is what I get back:

```
All work is finished
Doing work on 'a'
Doing work on 'b'
Doing work on 'c'
```

What I want to do is to wait until all work is finished then write the msg "All work is finished".

Comment: Check out reduce in bluebird. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p.then(DoWork(data))
```

This calls `DoWork` immediately. You want to pass a function to `.then`:

```
p.then(() => DoWork(data))
```

The reduce is otherwise fine. Example:

```js
delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

DoWork = work => delay(1000).then(() => console.log("did work", work));

AllMyWork = ["a","b","c"];
AllMyWork.reduce((p, data) => p.then(() => DoWork(data)), Promise.resolve())
.then(result => {
    console.log("All work is finished");
});
```